# Can you give a complete description in terms of series of the complex Lebesgue integrable functions?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

So, given a function c = a + ib, with a,b: N-->R, and c a Lebesgue Integrable function over N with the counting measure.

I may be wrong, but I believe that c is Lebesgue Integrable if and only if a and b are Lebesgue Integrable functions. So, in that case, the problem would be finding which functions f: N-->R are Lebesgue Integrable over N with the counting measure.

That happens when ∫|f|dμ < ∞ over N, and that Integral over N would be the infinite sum of |fn|, so the problem would be finding functions fn so that ∑|fn| < ∞.

I don't know if I'm going the right way, I'm really lost. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.